# How to change counter variable from numbers to letters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change a counter variable from a number to a letter? Say I have five sections that each read "Section A", "Section B", so on... And I want to change their href attributes as they are being mapped out from "section1" to "sectionA", "section2" to "sectionB", etc?

```
var sectionNumberLink = 0;
var sectionLetters = assessmentSections.map(function (section) {
    sectionNumberLink++;
    return  '<div class="assess-sec-link">' + '<a href="section' + 
        sectionNumberLink + '">' + "Section" + '</a>' + '</div>';  
}).join('');
```

Comment: String.fromCharCode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and [`String.prototype.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) to convert the number to a letter

Example:
**Warning:** This will fail if you have more than 26 sections

```js
function toLetter(number) {
  let base = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
  return String.fromCharCode(base - 1 + number);
}

console.log(toLetter(1)); // A
console.log(toLetter(2)); // B
```

If you need more than 26 sections, a bit more code is required:

```js
function toLetter(num) {
  let a = "A".charCodeAt(0);
  let result = '';
  for (let base = 1, mod = 26; (num -= base) >= 0;base = mod, mod *= 26) {
    result = String.fromCharCode(num % mod / base + a) + result;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(toLetter(1)); // A
console.log(toLetter(27)); // AA
```

In your code snippet you could use it like this:

```
let sectionLetters = assessmentSections.map((section, idx) => {
    return  `
      <div class="assess-sec-link">
        <a href="section${toLetter(idx + 1)}">Section</a>
      </div>`;  
}).join('');
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for all the info!

Answer (score 2):

You can use index to calculate the alphabet in the .map() method,

```js
//sample
var assessmentSections = ["section1", "section2", "section3"]

var sectionLetters = assessmentSections.map(function (section, index) {
     
    return  '<div class="assess-sec-link">' + '<a href="section' + 
        String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) - 1 + (index+1)) + '">' + "Section" + '</a>' + '</div>';  
    }).join('');
    
console.log(sectionLetters)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```js
const alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

//As @georg suggested, you could do it like: 
for(let c=1;c<=alphabet.length;c++){
  console.log("Section "+alphabet[c-1])
}
```

So, you can call `alphabet[number-1]` to change NUMBER to CHARACTER.

> *Remember arrays indexes start from 0, that's why it needs to be `number-1`.*

Comment: This is how I'd do that, however you could simply have `alphabet='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'` and `"Section" + alphabet[n-1]`. No need for the helper function.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to structure my HTML so I can use an `<ol type="A">` instead of `<div>`s, so that I get automatic ordering with uppercase letters automatically, without me having to do index-to-letter calculations:

```js
// create dummy data
var assessmentSections = Array.from({ length: 50 }, ( item, i ) => {
  return { url: i + 1 };
});
var sections = assessmentSections.map(( section, i ) => {
  return `<li class="assess-sec-link"><a href="${ section.url }">Section ${ i + 1 }</a></li>`;
});
document.querySelector( 'ol' ).innerHTML = sections.join( '' );
```

```html
<ol type="A"></ol>
```